# Différence entre les verbes tenter, tâcher, et essayer [de faire qch]

Tags: verbes

Je suppose qu'ils veulent exprimer « un effort/essai » d'une manière légèrement différente mais j'ignore comment et à quel point. Alors, c'est quoi la différence entre eux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Essayer de faire*" est une expression "générique" sans les petites nuances des deux autres termes.

"Tenter de"  c'est une Tentative avec une approche non certaine au départ, la faisabilité ou pas de réussite sera en général lié a des éléments extérieur indépendant de celui qui va "tenter"
-> "*Il faut tenter de réparer la voiture*" (même si ont fait tous les effort possible il est peut etre impossible de la réparer)

"*Tachez de*" est la même chose, avec la nuance ou cette fois la réussite ou pas est lié a l'humain directement concerné
-> "*Tachez d'être a l'heure a votre rendez-vous*" (ici ça ne dépend que de la bonne volonté de la personne et des moyens qu'il met en place pour y arriver)

"mixer" les 2: "*Tachez de tenter de réparer la voiture*" (faites l'effort d'essayer de réparer la voiture)  la voiture n'est peut être pas réparable, mais il faut que vous essayez

Comment: Ah trop bien - exactement ce que je cherchais ! Merci beaucoup.